# return specific indexes of multidimensional array without side effects

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given this multidimensional array:

```
a = [ [0,'abc'], [1,'def'] ]
```

I want to return just the keys (where keys are index 0s of subarray) and just the values (where values are index 1s of subarray):

```
a.keys
# => [0,1]

a.values
# => ['abc','def']
```

My solution to this is to use map to return a collection and use shift and pop to return the correct items:

```
a.map(&:shift)
=> [0, 1] 
a.map(&:pop)
=> ["abc", "def"]
```

Great it works, but then I noticed the side effects:

```
 a
 => [[], []]
```

Is there a way to get the functionality I have but without the side effects?

Comment: Not sure I understand the desired output, but `Hash[a]` will give you back `{0 => "abc", 1 => "def"}`. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: @infused my collection is an array of subarrays, not a hash. If it was a hash, it would be easy. I could just use keys and values methods. But with array there is no such keys and values method. I want all the first positions returned in one array and all the last positions returned in another array, as my example above achieves. The only problem is the side effects.

Comment: That's what converting the array to a Hash will do for you.  I just posted a full answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert your array of arrays to a Hash:

```
a = [ [0,'abc'], [1,'def'] ]
h = Hash[a]
```

Then get the keys and values:

```
h.keys #=> [0, 1]
h.values # => ['abc', 'def']
```

You can also get at the same results more directly (if the sub-arrays always have only 2 elements):

```
a = [ [0,'abc'], [1,'def'] ]
a.map(&:first) # => [0, 1]
a.map(&:last)  # => ['abc', 'def']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [ [0,'abc'], [1,'def'] ]

k,v = a.transpose
  #=> [[0, 1], ["abc", "def"]] 
k #=> [0, 1] 
v #=> ["abc", "def"]
```

I can't bring myself to write `keys` and `values`, as those words are generally reserved for hashes.